# General best practice for VLANs and domains

Tags: vlan, design, best-practices, performance

I recently took a job at a school. This is only my second position as an IT professional. My only experience with corporate networks is in a large school district at another school. They used VLANs to separate traffic based on device type: VoIP, wireless APs, desktops etc. They had one domain with an extensive OU tree to manage AD, and all VLANs were bridged.

At my new position, the network is set up far differently. They use three different domains at each site to segregate each user and device type. One domain each for admin and teacher, classroom, and lab computers. Each domain gets a VLAN.

Is this a common implementation? I want to find out what the best practice would be, and if this can cause network performance issues.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider the following general guidelines when implementing VLANs:

- Grouping devices by traffic patterns – Devices that communicate
  extensively between each other are good candidates to be grouped into
  a common VLAN.
- Grouping devices for security – It is often a good    practice to put
  servers and key infrastructure in their own VLAN,    isolating them
  from the general broadcast traffic and enabling    greater
  protection.
- Grouping devices by traffic types – As discussed
  in this How To, VoIP quality is improved by isolating VoIP devices to
  their own VLAN. Other traffic types may also warrant their own VLAN.
  Traffic types include network management traffic, IP multicast
  traffic such as video, file and print services, email, Internet
  browsing, database access, shared network applications, and traffic
  generated by peer-to-peer applications.
- Grouping devices geographically – In a network with limited
  trunking, it may be    beneficial to combine the devices in each
  location into their own    VLAN.

In your case (if I got it right) looks like they are grouping VLANS by "Department" (teachers, labs, classrooms...).

Here you may find some useful information regarding network implementation on an educational environment (Chapter 3): http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/solutions/Enterprise/Education/SchoolsSRA_DG/SchoolsSRA-DG.pdf